# Keras: image captioning network outputs constant caption

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to develop an image captioning network in Keras, but after training, the network outputs the same caption for every image.

This is my model:

```py
input1 = Input((64, 2048))
input2 = Input(shape = (40,))
encoder = Dense(embedding_dim, activation = 'relu')(input1)
emb = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, input_length = 40)(input2)
cell = AttentionDecoderCell(units)
decoder = RNN(cell, return_sequences = False)(emb, constants=encoder)

model = Model(inputs = [input1, input2], outputs = decoder)
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(), loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
```

Input1 is a feature vector extracted by InceptionV3 pretrained on imagenet.
Input2 is a sequence padded from the front.
The network is trying to predict the next word.

Majority of things happen within the custom cell

```py
class AttentionDecoderCell(keras.layers.GRUCell):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        super(AttentionDecoderCell, self).__init__(units, **kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        cap_shape = input_shape[0]
        features_shape = input_shape[1]
        self.a_w1 = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units), initializer="glorot_uniform", trainable=True, name = "attention_w1"
        )
        self.a_w2 = self.add_weight(
            shape=(features_shape[2], self.units), initializer="glorot_uniform", trainable=True, name = "attention_w2"
        )
        self.a_v = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, 1), initializer="glorot_uniform", trainable=True, name = "attention_v"
        )
        self.out_w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, vocab_size), initializer="glorot_uniform", trainable=True, name = "cell_output_weights"
        )
        self.out_b = self.add_weight(shape=(vocab_size,), initializer="zeros", trainable=True, name = "cell_output_bias")

        super(AttentionDecoderCell, self).build(input_shape[0])

    def call(self, inputs, states, constants, training = None):
        state = states[0]
        constant = constants[0]

        state_witht = K.expand_dims(state, 1)
        attention_hidden = K.tanh(K.dot(state_witht, self.a_w1) + K.dot(constant, self.a_w2))
        score = K.dot(attention_hidden, self.a_v)
        score = K.reshape(score, (score.shape.dims[:-1]))
        attention_weights = K.softmax(score)
        attention_weights = K.expand_dims(attention_weights,2)
        context_vector = attention_weights * constant
        context_vector = K.sum(context_vector, axis=1)

        gru_in = K.concatenate([inputs, context_vector], axis=-1)

        output, new_states = super(AttentionDecoderCell, self).call(gru_in, states, training = training)

        output = K.softmax(K.dot(output, self.out_w) + self.out_b)
        return output, new_states
    
    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super(AttentionDecoderCell, self).get_config()
        return base_config
```

My training loss looks like this:
[training loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRQtP.png)

When I try to test the network it outputs the same caption for every image or in other words output does not seem to be dependent on the input image.

I did not paste the full code here because it has quite a few lines, but you can find it here: [Full code](https://github.com/leon3428/ImageCaption)

After spending a lot of time on this, I am not certain what parts might be unclear so please ask me if any part needs to be explained in details.

Tnx for help!!!